# Spyder debugging not working when i pushes step into button, nothing happens

Tags: python, debugging, spyder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyYPV.png)

Dears; when I go into debug mode and pushes step into or current step. Nothing happens.please see attached screenshot. appreciate support.

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Updating **Spyder** to the latest `version 4.2.1` solves the problem.